# CSS to make an empty cell's border appear?

Tags: css

What CSS should I use to make a cell's border appear even if the cell is empty?

IE 7 specifically.

Comment: I'm having this issue in IE6! &nbsp; so far :(

Comment: problem is still actual in IE8 and IE9

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If I recall, the cell dosn't exist in some IE's unless it's filled with something...

If you can put a `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) to fill the void, that will usually work. Or do you require a pure CSS solution?

Apparently, IE8 shows the cells by default, and you have to hide it with `empty-cells:hide` But it doesn't work at all in IE7 (which hides by default).

Comment: Pure CSS would be nice.  I already have nbsps in there, but it feels dirty. :)

Comment: as far as I know, that is the only solution, it's what we do.

Comment: I would not do that. Add a <span style='width:0px;'></span> instead. Putting &nbsp; will cause a problem with Firefox when zoomed in.

Comment: Wow, that's a great little tip wbkang.

Answer (score 44):

Another way of making sure there is data in all cells:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("td:empty").html("&nbsp;");
    });
```

Comment: This works well since you can have it in a separate "ie.js" file for inclusion via conditional comments. In my case I didn't want to change my backend for an IE display bug.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me couple hundred conditional statements right there :)

Comment: Awesome!!! You just saved me a LOT of work!!!  Wish I could give more than just an upvote!!!

Comment: it looks like a hack to me

Answer (score 31):

If you set the `border-collapse` property to `collapse`, IE7 will show empty cells. It also collapses the borders though so this might not be 100% what you want

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
<html> <head> <title>Border-collapse Test</title> <style type="text/css"> td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td></td>
    <td />
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this should be the accepted answer since, as the poster points out, it has other side-effects, which may well be undesirable. It's also not true, at least as far as I can verify. Can you post a link to a working example?

Comment: I've added an example HTML document that shows the border showing even on blank cells.  Tested in IE7, fx3 and the latest safari. The main side-effect of border-collapse is you can't have double borders that look decent.  Also, missing cells can't be styled no matter how hard you try

Comment: border-collapse: collapse; worked fine for me (tested in IE7), thx :)

Answer (score 24):

The question asked for a CSS solution, but on the off-chance an HTML solution will do, here is one:

Try adding these two attributes to the table element:     **frame="box" rules="all"**
like this:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" frame="box" rules="all">
```

Comment: hmm. doesn't work if the empty cells are empty because they don't exist... (e.g. specifying a tr with 10 td cells but other trs have 100 or 1000 td cells)

Comment: Comment from 2018 here...these elements are now considered obsolete.

Answer (score 9):

I just found the following. It's standards compliant but it doesn't work in IE. sigh.

```
empty-cells: show
```

Comment: It does work in IE8 though, so just give it about a decade, and you're good to go.

Comment: Amusingly it also works for an standard html <table> in IE6 but not an ASP.NET table :)

Answer (score 9):

I happened across this question and haven't seen any answers that really addressed the issue.

The problem results because IE7 does not see any internal content for the cell; in programming terms the cell is resulting as a `null` and like most things, you cannot border a `null` or perform any action on it.  The browser needs an element/object that has a layout, in order to apply a border/layout.

Even empty `<div></div>` or `<span></span>` do not contain content, thus there is nothing to render, resulting in that `null` case again.

However, you can trick the browser into thinking the cell has content, by giving the empty `div/span` layout properties.  The easiest way is to apply the CSS style `zoom:1`.

```
<table>
   <tr><td>Foo</td>
       <td><span style="zoom:1;"></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

---

This workaround is better than using a `&nbsp;`, since it doesn't unnecessarily mess up screen readers, and isn't misrepresenting the value of the cell.  In newer browser you can use the `empty-cell:<show|hide>` alternative.

---

***Note:*** in lieu of Tomalak's comment, it should be understood that hasLayout has nothing to do with `null`, it was merely a comparison of how the browser interacts and renders hasLayout similarly to how a database or programming language interacts with nulls.  It is a strech, but I thought it might be easier to understand for those programmers turned web designers.

Comment: +1 Interesting. Though I'm not entirely convinced by your `null` analogy.

Comment: @Tomalak: It was the closest comparison I could make hasLayout to.  If no elements/objects have layout then the browser (IE) treats them differently and doesn't apply a lot of visual settings to them and their parents when rendering.  While isn't synonymous, I used the comparison loosely because Stack Overflow was conceptually a forum for programming Q&A, not necessarily web-design debugging - it's since grown :)  you have every right not to be convinced!

Comment: i tested th {border-bottom: 1px solid red; zoom:1;} in IE7 and it doesn't help. the border-bottom does not appear....

Comment: @nerdess: you'd have to create a question and show your exact case. You may have other stuff going on as browsers render the CSS differently; for example, if you set the same property twice (eg `color:blue;color:red;`) some use the first read setting(`blue`), others use the last setting (`red`).  That's regardless, of bordering issues, which can be affected by `border-collapse` and whatnot.  Because of all these idiosyncrasies, it's too difficult to determine what might be happening in your case.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, you shouldn't have any empty cells in a table. Either you have a table of data, and there's no data in that specific cell (which you should indicate with "-", or "n/a/", or something equally appropriate, or - if you must - &nbsp;, as suggested), or you have a cell that needs to span a column or row, or you're trying to achieve some layout with a table that you should be using CSS for.

Can we have a bit more detail?

Comment: I like this. Clarity increases.

Comment: If you have a very large table (tens of thousands of cells or larger) with lots of cells with no content (75-95%) it might be more performant to have empty cells.

Answer (score 5):

This question's old, but still a top result in Google, so I'll add what I've found:

Simply adding `border-collapse: collapse` to the table style fixed this problem for me in IE7 (and didn't affect the way they're displayed in FF, Chrome, etc).

Best to avoid the extraneous code of adding an `&nbsp;` or other spacing element when you can fix with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this can't be done with CSS;
You need to put a &nbsp; in every empty cell for the border to show in IE...

Answer (score 1):

empty-cell only fixed Firefox (YES I really did have this issue in Firefox) IE 7 & 8 were still problematic..

This worked for me in both Firefox 3.6.x, IE 7 & 8, Chrome, and Safari:

==============================

```
table {
*border-collapse: collapse;}

.sampleTD {
empty-cells: show;}
```

==============================

Had to use the * to make sure the table style was only applied to the IE browser.

Comment: Using css hacks might have unexpected consequenses so beware. Another way is to use conditional css.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you can't use non-breakable space:

```
var tn = document.createTextNode('\ ');
yourContainer.appendChild(ta);
```

Answer (score 1):

I create a div style that has the same font color as the background of your cell and write anything (usually a "-" "n/a" or "empty") to give the cell content. It shows up if you highlight the page, but when viewed normally looks how you want.

Comment: How does this improve/add to the 13 other answers?

Answer (score 1):

I use a mix of html and css to create cross browser table grids:

html

`<table cellspacing="1" style="background-color:#000;" border="0">`

css

```
td{background-color:#fff;}
```

I haven't seen any issues with any browsers so far.

Answer (score 0):

"IE" isn't a useful term in this context anymore now that IE8 is out.

IE7 always does "empty-cells:show" (or so I'm told ... Vista).
IE8 in any of its "Quirks" or "IE7 Standards" modes always does "empty-cells:hide".
IE8 in "Standards" mode defaults to "empty-cells:show" and supports the attribute via CSS.

As far as I know, every other browser has correctly supported this for several years (I know it was added in Firefox 2).

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking this from another website but:

```
.sampletable {
border-collapse: collapse;}

.sampleTD {
empty-cells: show;}
```

Use for the CSS for the table and TD element respectively.