# Table borders when no data in cell

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table

I have a table that has a couple of cells that do not contain data:

```
<table id="table_id2" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" border="1">
 <tr style="background-color:#D1DEB6"><td>Test 1</td><td class="y_n">Y</td></tr>
 <tr style="background-color:#C7D6A7"><td>Test 2</td><td class="y_n">N</td></tr>
 <tr style="background-color:#D1DEB6"><td></td><td class="y_n">Y</td></tr>
 <tr style="background-color:#C7D6A7"><td></td><td class="y_n">Y</td></tr>
</table>
```

I you look carefully you'll notice the borders are inconsistant. The borders appear but not for the cells without any data in them. Does anyone know a solution to this? I know you can put a `&nbsp` in to get the borders but this isn't an option for me the reason being that some cell have labels in them like:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
```

It's causing problems when say the Name is null then I'm missing the borders for the empty cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002/css-to-make-an-empty-cells-border-appear) is about the same issue, Internet Explorer not rendering empty cells.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. Should you remove your question if it's repeated? How would you do this?

Comment: You can vote to delete, however I'd leave it since Andrew's answer is a very specific solution for people who are databinding in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with CSS you could wrap your Eval call in a formatting function from your code behind page to check for an empty string and then return a `&nbsp;`:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# InsertNBSP(Eval("Name")) %>' />
```

On code behind:

```
public string InsertNBSP(string str)
{
    if(str == "")
       return "&nbsp;"
    else
       return str;
}
```