# Why do table cell borders disappear in Google Chrome when setting "visibility:hidden;" and "border-collapse: collapse;"?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I am a trying to style a HTML table using CSS. I need the ability to hide the content of single cells through CSS, since in the print layout (or with any other stylesheet) their  content has to be visible.
The table has a `<thead>` and a `<tbody>` section which, along each `<tr>`, `<th>` and `<td>`, have a border applied to them, so that so matter what I hide, the borders (even the outer ones) will always be shown.

In my stylesheet I set `border-collapse: collapse;` and the hide the cells I want to hide with `visibility:hidden;`, which works fine on most browsers, except Google Chrome (and some minor display glitches in Firefox, but I presume they come from the percentage in the widths..).

I also created a example of this behaviour:

```css
table.example {
  width:100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.example td{
  padding: 2px;
}

table.example .number {
  text-align:right;
}

table.example .null{
  visibility:hidden;
}

table.example .number.negative{
  color:red;
}

table.example .Date{
  text-align:center;
}

table.example th{
  background-color: #dedbde;
}

table.example, th.example, td.example,.example thead,.example tbody{
  border: 1px solid #a5a6a5;
}

#Demo1 .hideme.Col1,
#Demo1 .hideme.Col2 {
  visibility:hidden;
  border: 0;
}

#Demo1 {
  width: 50%;
}

.Col1 {
  width: 4%;
}

.Col2, .Col3,  .Col4  {
  width: 32%;
}
```

```html
<table class="example" id="Demo1">
  <thead>
    <tr class=" example">
      <th class="Col1 example"></th><th class="Col2 example">Title1</th><th class="Col3 example">Title2</th><th class="Col4 example">Title3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead><tbody>
  <tr class="r1 example odd first">
    <td class="Col1 example"><img src="image.png" alt="test" height="15px" width="15px"></td><td class="Col2 example"><a href="#" class="detaillink">        2865             </a></td><td class="Col3 example Date">10.06.2011</td><td class="Col4 example Date">10.07.2011</td>
  </tr><tr class="r2 example even">
  <td class="Col1 example"><img src="image.png" alt="test" height="15px" width="15px"></td><td class="Col2 example"><a href="#" class="detaillink">        2864             </a></td><td class="Col3 example Date">10.06.2011</td><td class="Col4 example Date">10.07.2011</td>
  </tr><tr class="r3 example odd">
  <td class="Col1 example hideme"><img src="image.png" alt="test" height="15px" width="15px"></td><td class="Col2 example hideme"><a href="#" class="detaillink">        2863             </a></td><td class="Col3 example hideme Date">10.06.2011</td><td class="Col4 example hideme Date">10.08.2011</td>
  </tr><tr class="r4 example even">
  <td class="Col1 example"><img src="image.png" alt="test" height="15px" width="15px"></td><td class="Col2 example"><a href="#" class="detaillink">        2863             </a></td><td class="Col3 example Date">10.06.2011</td><td class="Col4 example Date">10.08.2011</td>
  </tr><tr class="r5 example odd">
  <td class="Col1 example"><img src="image.png" alt="test" height="15px" width="15px"></td><td class="Col2 example"><a href="#" class="detaillink">        2299             </a></td><td class="Col3 example Date">10.05.2011</td><td class="Col4 example Date">10.06.2011</td>
  </tr><tr class="r6 example even">
  <td class="Col1 example null"></td><td class="Col2 example null"></td><td class="Col3 example Date null"></td><td class="Col4 example Date null"></td>
  </tr><tr class="r7 example odd">
  <td class="Col1 example"><img src="image.png" alt="test" height="15px" width="15px"></td><td class="Col2 example"><a href="#" class="detaillink">        1249             </a></td><td class="Col3 example Date">10.03.2011</td><td class="Col4 example Date">10.04.2011</td>
  </tr><tr class="r8 example even">
  <td class="Col1 example"><img src="image.png" alt="test" height="15px" width="15px"></td><td class="Col2 example"><a href="#" class="detaillink">        1248             </a></td><td class="Col3 example Date">10.03.2011</td><td class="Col4 example Date null"></td>
  </tr><tr class="r9 example odd">
  <td class="Col1 example"><img src="image.png" alt="test" height="15px" width="15px"></td><td class="Col2 example null"></td><td class="Col3 example Date">10.02.2011</td><td class="Col4 example Date">10.03.2011</td>
  </tr><tr class="r10 example even last">
  <td class="Col1 example"><img src="image.png" alt="test" height="15px" width="15px"></td><td class="Col2 example"><a href="#" class="detaillink">         563             </a></td><td class="Col3 example Date">10.02.2011</td><td class="Col4 example Date">20.03.2011</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see if you try this code, it even collapses the row with all cells hidden down to a small space.

This issue is not really critical for my current project, since most of the users will be on Internet Explorer, but since I couldn't find any solution and this problem might be affecting me in the future (and I'm sure other people have already run into this issue), I would really like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Off-hand, I see the border issue as being the `border:0;` style applied to `#Demo1 .hideme.Col1, #Demo1 .hideme.Col2`. As far as the shorter row, something tells me it has to do with visibility (even though It's supposed to retain real-estate, just be invisible).

Comment: Also, this other SO post may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002/css-to-make-an-empty-cells-border-appear/57006#57006

Comment: @Brad I tried to remove the `border: 0`, but it makes no change (at least not in Chrome). And you're right about the shorter row, but I can't seem to find a workaround for that (at least nothing that's not too ugly and works in all browsers).

Comment: @Brad That other SO post helped me with another problem of mine, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1**

If your TD are displaying only text, you can try this

> text-indent:-9999px;

Not sure about browser compatibility though, and it should only affect inline elements. No need to remove visibility with this.

---

Put a div inside each cell, this div will contain the elements that you have now in your cell, and then set `visibility:hidden` to that div only.

Example

```
<tr class="r2 example even">
  <td class="Col1 example">
    <div>
      what you want to hide here...
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ok, that solution sounds pretty straightforward (I should have thought of that myself...). Sadly it would add a lot of markup (the tables can already get pretty big, up to over a MB, they have to show a **lot** of data), and it feels kind of dirty.. a pure css solution would be awesome!

Comment: From your code I think you are only displaying text inside those cells? if so, you can put text-indent:-9999px; for the TDs you want not to show, but this will affect only inline elements as far as I know. Also I'm not sure about browser compatibility.

Comment: You're right, I display only text (and at most some smaller icons, also inline). Great Idea! It works, thanks a lot! It even takes care of the "missing" `<tr>`! Do you also have some idea on how to kepp the outer borders no matter what, but if two nearby cells are hidden, hide the border between them?

Comment: you could add another class which specifi only border-top:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; to all adjacent TDs except  the first in the row. That should do the job! Or you can play with the margins but then the layout will most surely break;

Comment: Note that if you display only text you could also go away easily with color:transparent; or color:white; whick will display the text inside the TDs transparent or white (if white is the color of your TDs background), this way you will simply not notice it.

Comment: In my previous comment about hiding borders of adjacent cells, you only have to set border-top and border-bottom, not also border-right, cause otherwise one border will always be present. My mistake.

Comment: @Jose The idea whith the additional class for the outer `<td>`'s is great, it wouldn't add that much markup, and I don't see why it wouldn't work. Setting the color to the background color could clearly also work, but it feels kind of hacky, and changing the background color would make problems.. And nice trick with the `color:transparent`, that was new for me. But all options work, nice job! Thansk a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the border of the tr as well as the td seems to fix it for me.

```
.collateral-tabs .std tr,
.collateral-tabs .std td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```