# add css border to empty html <td></td>

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS to make an empty cell's border appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002/css-to-make-an-empty-cells-border-appear)

im using css to add a border to  tags. The issue is no border is created if the tag is empty ex `<td></td>`.

One work around is to use the white space `&nbsp;` but that would involve writing a script to check if the data is going to be empty or not.

Is there a better way to use the CSS so that the border will show?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
table { empty-cells:show; }
```