# IE8 td borders not consistent

Tags: css, html-table

I can't figure out why the borders on some of the cells are showing up and others are not:
http://jsfiddle.net/webedge/rt5pk/

I have applied all styles via CSS.

There are some images missing, that I haven't uploaded anywhere, which would answer some of the td padding, but my major concern are the td borders.

Comment: Try adding `&nbsp;` to those empty `<td></td>`.

Comment: See this old post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002/css-to-make-an-empty-cells-border-appear

Comment: Tried that, thought it might be it, no dice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's being caused by the `position:relative` on your `td`s - if you remove this the layout is fixed.

If you need the positioning for positioning other elements inside the `td` you might try adding an extra `<span>` or `<div>` within the cell, and position these extra elements?

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
table.chart { border-collapse: separate; }
```

It's good to specify as many attributes as possible to look consistent across all browsers, otherwise you'll need a CSS reset.

http://jsfiddle.net/EL7NQ/

Comment: unfortunately in IE8 your jsfiddle doesn't render any different for me

Comment: ah, I have IE9 and it fixed the issue for me.