# IE table first column whitespace

Tags: html, css

Im making a page (for IE) where is shows some values in a table format. But somehow there's some kind of whitespace before the first column making it uneven with the following columns.
i just want the columns to be aligned
http://i49.tinypic.com/14b3kuh.jpg

```
out.println("<div id='tablePos'>");
out.println("<ul class='ulStyle'>");
out.println("<li>");           
out.println("<table border='1'>");
out.println("<div id='divTableForms'>");
out.println("<tr id='process'><td>PROCESS</td></tr>");
while(rs.next()){
String process = rs.getString(2);
String processtype = rs.getString(1);
out.println("<tr id='process'><td id='process2'>"+processtype + "-" +process+"</td></tr>");
            }
out.println("<tr id='process'><td id='process2'></td></tr>");
out.println("</div>");
out.println("</table>");
out.println("</li>");
```

Comment: it ll be better if u add any working example in jsfiddle or jsbin....

Comment: your html code is not well-form .why your headers(process_type+process),inputs in seperate tables.merge headers,inputs in one table for resolve it.

Comment: @MajidTaheri could you suggest a way of displaying it like that in a dynamic way since there are more than 1 processes per process type and i can add processes and prcesstypes later on. the problem for me would be dealing with the empty cells within the process type column if it was separate and more organized if it were to show only the prcoessType once and left empty cells before the next process type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,I think its because of ur divTableForms div... And second, u have used  out.println("< tr id='process'>< td id='process2'>< /td>< /tr>");

But i dont get for wat u have included it.... Abd finally never use the same id for multiple tag... Particularly inside loop never use it..

Comment: oh i added that as an empty cell to make an equal number of rows to match the next column which had 50. but that doesn't affect the whitespace before the PROCESS field as shown in the picture

Answer (score 0):

empty Table-Data (TD element) always was problem.  view this http://bignosebird.com/docs/h34.shtml  OR [CSS to make an empty cell's border appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002/css-to-make-an-empty-cells-border-appear).

```
out.println("<tr id='process'><td id='process2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>");
```

also id attribute value  must be unique in html document . your code duplicate 'process' identifier in html document use class instead of  Id Attribute

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. but what the real problem was as shown in the picture the PROCESS field should be aligned with the first row of the next column which was Operation Machine