# How to assign border to tr?

Tags: html

I have created table like this.If one of the cell is blank,cell get disappear.I want atleast border of that cell,if value is not there.If I try to assign a border to tr,no effect.

```
<table border="1">

    <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS to make an empty cell's border appear?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002/css-to-make-an-empty-cells-border-appear)

Comment: The heading of the question refers to `tr` border, the text discusses blank cell borders, but the code sample has no blank cell. It is very unclear what is being asked here.

Answer (score 1):

firstly its working in my browser if any of the cell is blank.
and if its not working in your browser then give **height** and **border** to **td**.
and css it better idea than using attribute.
refer [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) to understand css for border.

Answer (score 0):

try this css for a border on a cell:

```
td{
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 20px;
    }
```

try to use this css for a border on a row if you want it on a row:

```
tr{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Please note that the height of 20px is as high as you want, it's just an example.

Comment: I don't want to create a css for small table.

Comment: Ok, if you don't want to use `CSS`, maybe you should put that in your question.

Comment: Either way, it doesn't answer the question. He wants the border to appear on empty cells.

Comment: exactly and that works if you give your cells a specific height. Your epmty cell is a CSS solution too....

Answer (score 0):

You could set border-top and border-bottom for all td elements inside the tr and border-left / border-right for the first and last td inside.

Answer (score 0):

This is because empty table cells are hidden by default. To make them appear, you can use this CSS:

```
table { empty-cells: show; }
```

More information: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/HTML/emptycells.html
Browser support: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html

This CSS is supported in everything from IE8 upwards (and IE7 shows empty cells anyway, as far as I can tell).

(if you want to do this inline, without a separate CSS file, try `<table style="empty-cells: show;">`)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get a cell border, you've to set it on a td:

```
<td style〓"border: 1px solid #gfdfgf">
```