# CSS does not apply to IE<8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
.csstdhighlight
{
    border-left-color: Red;
    border-right-color: Red;
    border-bottom-color: Red;
    border-top-color: Red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: White;
}
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .csstdhighlight
    {
        border:1px solid red;
        background-color: White;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="csstdhighlight">foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am applying border to table cell, but CSS isn't applied to IE versions earlier than 8.

Comment: You know, this can be simplified to `border: 1px solid red; background: white;`

Comment: i check ur code background applies but border not applies

Comment: Please post the html your css applies to and if possible create a http://jsfiddle.net showing the issue for testing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2sjaZ/18/  see in IE 6/7

Comment: I've just checked your fiddle. It works fine in IE7.

Comment: see in 6................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in IE 6/7:

```
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .csstdhighlight
    {
        border:1px solid red;
        background-color: White;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="csstdhighlight">foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The table cell around "foo" has a red border. http://jsfiddle.net/rUcnv/

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your CSS, the issue here is your table cell that don't have a content. In IE7 an empty table cell don't exist which means the border style will not be render.

See related topic about empty cell [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002/css-to-make-an-empty-cells-border-appear).