# TD Borders from a table, not showing in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, html-table, border

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS to make an empty cell’s border appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002/css-to-make-an-empty-cells-border-appear)

I know this question has been asked a lot before, I tried adding &nbsp between every      `<td> </td>` tags and it didn't work well, I'm guessing there's some kind of problem in the CSS, but I haven't been able to spot it, my tables shows alright with Firefox and Chrome, but whenever I try with IE8, there are some borders missing. HTML and table's CSS below, as well as screenshots.
The HTML of the table, was generated from a PHP Script.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href ="layout_ie.css"/> 
        <![endif]-->

        <!--[if !IE]> -->
        <link rel ="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href ="layout.css"/>
        <!-- <![endif]-->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
          <title>Calendario de Capacitaciones</title>
    </head>
    <body>

   <table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">
        <tr class = "calendar-row"> 
            <td class = "calendar-day-head">Lunes</td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-head">Martes</td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-head">Miércoles</td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-head">Jueves</td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-head">Viernes</td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-head">Sábado</td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-head">Domingo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class = "calendar-row">

            <td  class ="calendar-day-np">&nbsp; </td>
            <td  class ="calendar-day-np">&nbsp; </td>
            <td  class ="calendar-day-np">&nbsp; </td>
            <td  class ="calendar-day-np">&nbsp; </td>
            <td  class ="calendar-day-np">&nbsp; </td>
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">1</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">2</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="calendar-row">
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">3</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">4</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">5</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">6</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">7</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">8</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">9</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="calendar-row">
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">10</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">11</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">12</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">
                &nbsp<div class = "day-number">13</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">14</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">15</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">16</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="calendar-row">
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">17</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">18</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">19</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp 
                <div class = "day-number">20</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">21</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">22</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">23</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="calendar-row">
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">24</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">25</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">26</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">27</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">28</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">29</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>

            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">&nbsp
                <div class = "day-number">30</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calendar-row">
            <td  bgcolor="#FFFFFB" class = "calendar-day">
                &nbsp<div class = "day-number">31</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>&nbsp
            </td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class = "calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>        

    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
    table.calendar    {table-layout:fixed;margin-top:5em ;margin-left:15em; border-left:1px solid #999; }
tr.calendar-row  {  }
td.calendar-day  { min-height:80px; font-size:11px; position:relative;border:1px solid #999; } * html div.calendar-day { height:80px; }
td.calendar-day:hover  { background:#eceff5; }
td.calendar-day-np  {  background:#eee; min-height:80px; } * html div.calendar-day-np { height:80px; }
td.calendar-day-head { background:#ccc; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; width:135px; padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #999; border-top:1px solid #999; border-right:1px solid #999; }
div.day-number    { background:#999; padding:5px; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; float:right; margin:-5px -5px 0 0; width:20px; text-align:center; }
/* shared */
td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np {  max-width:50px;  padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #999; border-right:1px solid #999; }
```

***Screenshots:***

**How it looks in IE8.**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7w6H.jpg]

**How it should look, (taken from Firefox).**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0xzI.png]

Comment: Well, the answer has nothing to do with adding &nbsp, or filling blank spaces between as I stated, I did try that solution when I posted this. 
How is this an exact duplicate of the post above?
I'm not complaining, I'm just wondering how is this a duplicate, so I don't make the mistake again whenever I post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do this in your CSS:

```
td.calendar-day {
min-height:80px; 
font-size:11px;
border:1px solid #999 !important;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked, the borders look thicker, but I can work around that. Can you explain what's the logic behind this?

Comment: simply overwrite the border of any rule, so earlier was not important.

Comment: without `border-collapse:collapse` set to the table itself every `td` will have a border all the way around it, essentially duplicating the border. collapsing the border will ensure there is only one border per `td` divider.