# XSLT Grouping on one subnode through multiple higher level nodes

Tags: xslt

I'm fairly new to XSLT but am trying to get an XML file to display a certain node set through XSLT. I am using XSL 1.0. The xml looks like this:

```
<...>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="Weight" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/21/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="75" unit="lbs" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="BMI" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/21/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="14.6" unit="98" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="Weight" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/20/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="255" unit="lbs" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="BMI" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/20/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="49.8" unit="98" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="Blood Pressure" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/20/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="100/76" unit="mm Hg" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
</...>
```

What I want the output to look like is something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>5/21/2013</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Weight: 75lbs</td>
    <td>BMI: 14.6 90</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5/20/2013</td>
    <td>Blood Pressure: 100/76 mm Hg</td>
    <td>Weight: 255lbs</td>
    <td>BMI: 49.8 90</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Basically, group by the effectiveTime (within the observation node), and put the blood pressure, the weight and the bmi in subsequent columns. I also need to have a blank table cell if a particular code displayname is not present for that particular date (see blood pressure not listed for the first date).

Thanks for any help. I'm picking up the XSLT, but it's taking time since there is so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version of solution using XSLT 1.0 ... rather than using a variable of field names, I coded the column handling for each one.

```
T:\ftemp>type entries.xml 
<entries>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="Weight" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/21/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="75" unit="lbs" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="BMI" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/21/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="14.6" unit="98" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="Weight" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/20/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="255" unit="lbs" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="BMI" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/20/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="49.8" unit="98" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="Blood Pressure" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/20/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="100/76" unit="mm Hg" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
</entries>
T:\ftemp>call xslt entries.xml entries1.xsl 
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>5/21/2013</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Weight: 75 lbs</td>
      <td>BMI: 14.6 98</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5/20/2013</td>
      <td>Blood Pressure: 100/76 mm Hg</td>
      <td>Weight: 255 lbs</td>
      <td>BMI: 49.8 98</td>
   </tr>
</table>
T:\ftemp>type entries1.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="times" match="entry"
         use="organizer/component/observation/effectiveTime/@value"/>

<xsl:template match="entries">
  <!--create the table-->
  <table>
    <!--grouped by time-->
    <xsl:for-each select="entry[generate-id(.)=
  generate-id(key('times',
                  organizer/component/observation/effectiveTime/@value)[1])]">
      <tr>
        <!--subset of time-->
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
                  organizer/component/observation/effectiveTime/@value,' ')"/>
        </td>
        <!--the fields in order-->
        <xsl:variable name="values" 
          select="key('times',
                      organizer/component/observation/effectiveTime/@value)/
                  organizer/component/observation"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$values/code[@displayName='Blood Pressure']">
            <td>
              <xsl:for-each
                select="$values[code/@displayName='Blood Pressure']">
                <xsl:value-of 
          select="concat('Blood Pressure: ',value/@value,' ',value/@unit)"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise><td>&#xa0;</td></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$values/code[@displayName='Weight']">
            <td>
              <xsl:for-each
                select="$values[code/@displayName='Weight']">
                <xsl:value-of 
                    select="concat('Weight: ',value/@value,' ',value/@unit)"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise><td>&#xa0;</td></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$values/code[@displayName='BMI']">
            <td>
              <xsl:for-each
                select="$values[code/@displayName='BMI']">
                <xsl:value-of 
                  select="concat('BMI: ',value/@value,' ',value/@unit)"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise><td>&#xa0;</td></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
T:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Comment: Both xsl 1.0 solutions work which is great. This one gives me more control for exceptions in the output (but I have the other for future reference). The only things I have to deal with are 1) there may be more than 2 dates and I only need the top two and 2) There might be multiple entries for the same date and I need the last set for the last two dates.

Comment: This is a pretty monolithic and repetitive solution, it would benefit from refactoring. The `<xsl:choose>` could be abstracted into a named template, for example, like this: http://bpaste.net/show/YRwcsRexg9vA81kS0oAl/

Comment: @Tomalak Only issue with pulling it out into it's own template is that one of the 3 options doesn't need to display the unit, just the value so it's not uniform across all of them. Otherwise, I would absolutely pull it out for reuse to cut down on all the lines of code.

Comment: @Tomalak - Can that abstracted template be done to pull only the first item in the document order (per the distinction in the other post)?

Comment: @jjasper Yes, as indicated in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255255/xslt-grouping-on-one-subnode-through-multiple-higher-level-nodes/18258251?noredirect=1#comment26779464_18258251).

Comment: @Tomalak - I've modified your abstract like so: <xsl:apply-templates select=".//observation[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('vs_times', effectiveTime/@value)[1])][position() &lt; 3]" /> but not getting the first two dates. I'm still getting all the entries.

Comment: Refactoring has its place, but pragmatism also has its place.

Comment: @G. Ken Holman - if i get multiple values for the same date, how do I get just the first one? so it's grouped by date but there could be 4 weights on the same date. I want the first one in document order.

Comment: That is a very fundamental question with a straightforward answer ... simply add `[1]` at the end of the XPath address in the `<xsl:for-each>` that repositions the current node to the appropriate value:  rather than reposition to all of the values for a given display, you then will be positioning only to the first.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which version of XSLT, so I've assumed 2.0:

```
T:\ftemp>type entries.xml 
<entries>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="Weight" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/21/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="75" unit="lbs" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="BMI" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/21/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="14.6" unit="98" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="Weight" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/20/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="255" unit="lbs" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="BMI" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/20/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="49.8" unit="98" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <organizer>
      <component>
        <observation>
          <code displayName="Blood Pressure" />
          <effectiveTime value="5/20/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
          <value value="100/76" unit="mm Hg" />
        </observation>
      </component>
    </organizer>
  </entry>
</entries>
T:\ftemp>call xslt2 entries.xml entries.xsl 
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>5/21/2013</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Weight: 75 lbs</td>
      <td>BMI: 14.6 98</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5/20/2013</td>
      <td>Blood Pressure: 100/76 mm Hg</td>
      <td>Weight: 255 lbs</td>
      <td>BMI: 49.8 98</td>
   </tr>
</table>
T:\ftemp>type entries.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="entries">
  <!--dictate the order of the columns this way-->
  <xsl:variable name="fields" select="('Blood Pressure','Weight','BMI')"/>
  <!--create the table-->
  <table>
    <!--grouped by time-->
    <xsl:for-each-group select="entry"
              group-by="organizer/component/observation/effectiveTime/@value">
      <tr>
        <!--subset of time-->
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
                  organizer/component/observation/effectiveTime/@value,' ')"/>
        </td>
        <!--the fields in order-->
        <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
          <xsl:variable name="this" 
    select="current-group()[organizer/component/observation/code/@displayName=
    current()]/organizer/component/observation/value"/>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$this">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of 
                    select="concat(.,': ',$this/@value,' ',$this/@unit)"/>
              </td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><td>&#xa0;</td></xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
T:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Comment: My mistake... I'm using XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="kObservationByTime" match="observation" use="effectiveTime/@value" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Blood Pressure</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>BMI</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="group" select="
        *//observation[
          generate-id() 
          =
          generate-id(key('kObservationByTime', effectiveTime/@value)[1])
        ][position() &gt; last() - 3]
      " />
        <xsl:sort select="effectiveTime/@value" order="descending" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="observation" mode="group">
    <xsl:variable name="time" select="effectiveTime/@value" />
    <xsl:variable name="thisGroup" select="key('kObservationByTime', $time)" />

    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($time, ' ')" /></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="$thisGroup[code[@displayName = 'Blood Pressure']]" /></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="$thisGroup[code[@displayName = 'Weight']]" /></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="$thisGroup[code[@displayName = 'BMI']]" /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="observation">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(value/@value, ' ', value/@unit))" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives you

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Blood Pressure</th>
<th>Weight</th>
<th>BMI</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5/21/2013</td>
<td></td>
<td>75 lbs</td>
<td>14.6 98</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5/20/2013</td>
<td>100/76 mm Hg</td>
<td>255 lbs</td>
<td>49.8 98</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

http://www.xmlplayground.com/O9Z9DT

This solution uses an `<xsl:key>` for grouping.

The `[position() &gt; last() - 3]` predicate selects the last 2 groups for display. The alternative, `[position() &lt; 3]`, would select the first two. Both work in document order, while `<xsl:sort>` only affects output order.

Note that [due to an unwise choice in date formatting](http://xkcd.com/1179/), ordering your results sensibly isn't possible with pretty code.

The non-pretty code to sort your entries by date would look like this:

```
<xsl:sort select="
  concat(
    substring-after(substring-after(substring-before(effectiveTime/@value, ' '), '/'), '/'),
    '-',
    10 + substring-before(effectiveTime/@value, '/'),
    '-',
    10 + substring-before(substring-after(effectiveTime/@value, '/'), '/')
  )
" order="descending" />
```

... or you simply use a sensible date format and the pain goes away. ;)

Comment: Are you referring to the date format in the xml nodes? I could adjust that if necessary. Right now, it's being pulled as a date/time field from a database stored procedure and could easily enough be formatted into something else. However, the date AND time are necessary for this instance. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I note that this doesn't give the requested &nbsp; character in the table cell as requested by the original poster.  That may be required by him in order to engage table borders.

Comment: On the topic of showing empty cells I suggest [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/57002/18771), though I tend to use `border-collapse: collapse;` on the table. In any case, showing a non-existent property as `&nbsp;` from the XSLT is possible, but I don't know if it's worth doing if you can solve it via CSS.

Comment: Could I not put a condition around the <td></td> portion of the template based on that particular value being in place and if not have an else/otherwise to display <td>&nbsp;</td>? Also, there may be instances where there are more than 2 distinct dates. How can this be tweaked to show only the last two. They will be ordered in the xml (from the database output) in descending order correctly.

Comment: Another possibility in terms of dealing with dates is using the [EXSLT date functions](http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html) as far as your XSLT processor supports them. I'd recommend using them to *format* the date only, while keeping the date in the XML in ISO8601 for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yes, you can put a condition around every `<td>` and render a `&nbsp;` if there's no respective value. It just bloats the source, because it would be a full-blown `<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$thisGroup[code[@displayName = 'BMI']"><xsl:apply-templates select="$thisGroup[code[@displayName = 'BMI'] /></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>&#x160;</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>` three times (or how many columns you ever have. Go for CSS if you can.

Comment: @jjasper Note that I've modified the solution in a way to allow showing the first/last N groups only.

Comment: @Tomalak - That position is quite helpful. I'm able to get the 2 dates that I want. Can it also be applied within the output. For instance if one date has 3 blood pressures, I want the first one in document order and then skip to the next date

Comment: Sure, you can use `$thisGroup[code[@displayName = 'Blood Pressure']][1]` to explicitly select the first one in document order. Also be sure to have a look at http://bpaste.net/show/YRwcsRexg9vA81kS0oAl/ for an alternative approach to G. Ken Holman's solution.