# How to display empty entries in DataTables properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

When I insert empty entries into a table created using DataTables they aren't displayed right. How to fix this?

[image]

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z4g144j6/)

**HTML**

```
<table id="userTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//Add activity as row
function addRow(user,age,country)
{
    var table = $('#userTable').DataTable();
        table.row.add([  user,
                         age,
                         country
                      ]).draw();
        table.columns.adjust().draw();
}

//Default
$(document).ready(function () {
    //initializing table
    var table = $('#userTable').dataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [ [5, 10, 15, 25, -1], [5, 10, 15, 25, "All"] ],
        "pageLength": 5,
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 2 ] }]
    });
    //Adding sample rows
    addRow("a","12","");
    addRow("b","13","USA");
    addRow("c","14","");
    addRow("d","15","");
    addRow("e","18","");
    addRow("f","17","UK");
    addRow("g","16","USA");
    addRow("h","11","");
    addRow("i","10","");
});
```

Comment: Looks fine on chrome. Maybe browser issue?

Comment: It looks like that on firefox.

Comment: Yea looks to be a browser issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002/css-to-make-an-empty-cells-border-appear

Comment: Looks fine on IE, Firefox, and Safari as well... What browser are you using? You could try adding &nbsp; instead of "".

Comment: Firefox 34.0.5 is my browser. Ok I will add &nbsp;.